# php multiply and divide

Tags: php

It says "server error" when I try to submit a value.

In my first file `index.php` I have this and then i have it submit to another maybe it could also submit to itself?

```
<html>
<body>

<h1>Sale Calculator </h1>

<form action="process.php" method="post">

Cost of item:

<input type="text" name="itemAmt" required="required" />

Percentage of discount:

<select name="saleAmt">
<option value="5">5% off</option>
<option value="10">10% off</option>
<option value="15">15% off</option>
<option value="20">20% off</option>
<option value="25">25% off</option>
<option value="30">30% off</option>
<option value="40">40% off</option>

<!-- Ill fill out more values later -->

</select>

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">

</form>

</body>
</html>

**Then in the second php file process.php I have put this:**



 <?php
    $itemAmt = $_POST['itemAmt'];
    $saleAmt = $_POST['saleAmt'];
    $dollarSaleAmt;
    $totalCost;

    function calculateDiscount($itemAmt, $saleAmt, &$dollarSaleAmt, &$totalCost)
    {

    $dollarSaleAmt = $itemAmt * ($saleAmt / 100);
    $totalCost = $itemAmt – $dollarSaleAmt;
    }

    calculateDiscount($itemAmt, $saleAmt, $dollarSaleAmt, $totalCost);
    ?>

    <html>
    <body>
    The total discount <?php echo $_POST['itemAmt']; ?> .

    <br />

    The final cost minus the discount of <?php echo $_POST['saleAmt']; ?> .

    <br />
    Discount
    <?php echo $dollarSaleAmt; ?>
    <br />
    Total value:
    <?php echo $totalCost; ?>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: what is the error message?

Comment: Also can you shorten your example so that the least amount of code shows your error

Comment: Maybe this is a problem in your post and not your code, but your minus sign in `$totalCost = $itemAmt – $dollarSaleAmt;` is not actually a minus sign, but an em or en dash. I tried to copy and paste this code and run it, and ran into that issue. Otherwise, the code ran fine for me.

Answer (score 2):

When I paste your code into a [webbased PHP interpreter](http://codepad.viper-7.com/ih3uxi), I get the following error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '–' (T_STRING) in /code/ih3uxi
>   on line 11 PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '–' (T_STRING) in
>   /code/ih3uxi on line 11

Please replace your fake minus (`–`) with a real minus (`-`).

```
echo ord('–'); // 226
echo ord('-'); // 45
```

You need the 45 one.

Comment: ok yep that seems to have fixed it used a dash instead of the minus sign!